# Как в Netbeans для C++ посмотреть тип переменной?

Tags: c++, netbeans

Гуглил, пытался угадать, читал их шпаргалки - не нашел. Неужели NetBeans этого просто не умеет?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Где посмотреть? В отладчике?

Comment: Ну это обычная фича любой нормальной IDE по моим представлениям. Например в CLion наводим курсор на переменную (даже если она auto), жмем Ctr+Q, видим документацию и (!) тип, например std::string. В IDEA то же самое для Scala и Java, только можно без документации даже, Alt+=, выглядит так http://i.imgur.com/rY2hOtJ.png Не в отладчике, просто в редакторе. Как это сделать в NetBeans не нашел.

Comment: Нужно признать, что наилучшая поддержка С++ сейчас только в QtCreator и Visual Studio, CLion пока не конкурент, в остальных редакторах поддержка для галочки.

Comment: zenden2k, я извиняюсь, а чего именно вам не хватает в CLion? И, сказать по правде, в QtCreator я тоже не нашел отображения типов переменных. На самом деле он документацию вообще не показывает у меня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans не поддерживает отображение типа переменной.

Есть workaround, если вы находитесь под отладчиком. Добавьте watch следующего содержания:

```
typeid(yourVariableNameHere).__name
```

...и вы получите тип переменной. Если у вас указатель, то для получения реального типа объекта указатель надо будет разыменовать.

Чтобы это работало, вам надо будет включить заголовочный файл:

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

P.S. Да, всё настолько печально. Используйте нормальные среды разработки.

Comment: Спасибо. А вы чем пользуетесь? Под Linux самым нормальным вариантом на данный момент выглядит CLion.

Comment: @afiskon Visual Studio, когда-то давно C++ Builder. :) Для линукса на плюсах не писал. Самым перспективным выглядит CLion, JetBrains знают своё дело.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же NetBeans может показать информацию о типе.

1. Просто наведите курсор с нажатым Ctrl на что угодно. Всплывет подсказка в которой будет тип
2. Можно окрыть Window -> IDE Tools -> C/C++ Documentation. Тут просто будет появляться документация из текущего контекста (для того элемента на котором курсор)

Работает на любых идентификаторах. Даже если тип auto.